# Hidden Applications

Tags: macos, disk-space

When I click on the Apple Logo->About This Mac->Storage it says that I have 45GB worth of applications

[image].

I downloaded and ran OmniDisk Sweeper it says that it found 22GB worth of files in total [image].

Any ideas how I can find and remove these "applications" and free up disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running OmniDisk Sweeper with elevated privileges found the large files. To do so one should right-click on the app icon, click "Show Package Contents" and open the MacOS folder. Then open the terminal, type sudo and drag and drop the contents of MacOS to the terminal window, press enter input the password and the app should launch.